# I can't process the element that comes from external API call

Tags: python, api, apache-beam

I am trying to do an external call to the Google Natural Language API in a DoFn class:

```
class RequestAPI(beam.DoFn):
    def setup(self):
        self._client = language_v1.LanguageServiceClient()

    def process(self, element):
        classify = False
        if element['lang'] =='en':
            classify = True
        document = {"document": {
            "type_": "PLAIN_TEXT", "content": element['text']},
            "features": {
                "extract_entities": True,
                "extract_document_sentiment": True,
                "extract_entity_sentiment": True,
                "classify_text": classify,
            },
            "encoding_type": "UTF8"
        }

        response = self._client.annotate_text(request=document)
        new_element = element
        new_element['analysis'] = {'sentences': response.sentences,
                                   'score': response.document_sentiment.score,
                                   'magnitude': response.document_sentiment.magnitude,
                                   'tokens': response.tokens,
                                   'lang_api': response.language,
                                   'entities': response.entities
                                   }
        print(new_element)
        return new_element
```

And, I call this class from:

```
data_enrich: PCollection = (
            tweets_data | beam.ParDo(RequestAPI())
            | 'write data' >> beam.io.WriteToText('data.txt')
    )
```

The problem is that when I recieve the response and return the new element I get the following error: `TypeError: cannot pickle 'google.protobuf.pyext._message.RepeatedCompositeContainer' object [while running 'ParDo(RequestAPI)']`

I already check that the ptoblem is not the API response or the type of the new element (is a dict).

I am using python 3.7 and the apache beam version 2.43.

I hope that you can help me or give me any clue about what is happenig.

I try it before with a Map transform and it give it to me the same error, and I saw a few examples of external call with apache beam and the examples use DoFn classes, so I tried it but it didn't work. It gives me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The output of a DoFn needs to be an iterator. According to the [documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#pardo) (chapter 4.2.1.2)

> Your process method should accept an argument element, which is the
> input `element`, and **return an iterable** with its output values. You can
> accomplish this by **emitting** individual elements **with yield** statements.
> You can also use a **return** statement with an iterable, like a **list** or a
> **generator**.

So you should change the output of `RequestAPI` to

```
return [new_element]
```

or even better

```
yield new_element
```